# Обработка SQL запроса

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость обработать запрос на получение максимального значения в базе данных. 
Вот как запрос делается:

```
function selectMaxId(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql="SELECT MAX(exp) FROM wp_cart ";
    $result =$wpdb->query($sql);
    return $result;}
```

По факту это wordpress, но можно перевести на человеческий.  
`global $wpdb;`, можно сказать, заменяет `mysql_conect`.  
`$wpdb->query($sql);`, думаю, понятно, что это `mysql_query`.

При выводе даных (использовал `print_r`, так красивее получилось):

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MAX(exp)] => 2 ) )
```

Попробовал так:

```
$theExp =  mysql_result($theExper, 0);
   print_r ($theExper);
```

Получил вот такой ответ:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\video.lc\wp-content\themes\ifs\page-exp.php on line 11
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MAX(exp)] => 2 ) )
```

Помогите. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить значение поля БД в переменную, можно использовать `$wpdb->get_var()`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/ru:wpdb_Class#SELECT_a_Variable

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectMaxId(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql="SELECT MAX(exp) FROM wp_cart ";
    $result =$wpdb->query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        return $row[0];
}
```

Пробуй так